# Azure Data Factory - Call an EXE file which is in Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, powershell-remoting

I have a requirement to call an EXE file with parameter. The EXE file is in Azure VM. We need to call the EXE file from the Azure Data Factory.
I would like to know possible options to achieve this and if anyone came across scenarios and how to achieve it.

Comment: What exactly is this exe doing and why you want to call it from ADF? I think there are some issues with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the exe file is in Azure VM, you need using the [self-hosted integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to access the file in it:

- The integration runtime (IR) is the compute infrastructure that Azure
  Data Factory uses to provide data-integration capabilities across
  different network environments. For details about IR, see Integration
  runtime overview.
- A self-hosted integration runtime can run copy activities between a
  cloud data store and a data store in a private network. It also can
  dispatch transform activities against compute resources in an
  on-premises network or an Azure virtual network. The installation of
  a self-hosted integration runtime needs an on-premises machine or a
  virtual machine inside a private network.

Download and install the integration on your Azure VM. It's more like this tutorial: [Copy data to or from a file system by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system)

**Update1:**

We can not call or execute the exe in ADF! Data Factory is focus on data moving, it will consider the exe as a file.

**Update2:**

We can use PowerShell to run the DF pipeline, but in Data Factory pipeline, PowerShell script is not supported. You could vote this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19119145-powershell-script-support-in-activity):
[image]

HTH.

Comment: We have the self hosted IR installed on the Azure VM where the EXE is present. But, now I am not able to figure out how do I call EXE from the Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Hi @SanjayJanardhan,  We can not call or execute the exe in ADF! Data Factory is focus on data moving, it will consider the exe as a file.

Comment: Thank you @LeonYue. I was thinking like as we have option of the PowerShell remoting, can we leverage in this scenario. But, I am stuck with calling the Powershell script from the ADF as there is no proper documentation

Comment: @SanjayJanardhan We can use PowerShell to run the DF pipeline, but in Data Factory pipeline, PowerShell script is not supported. You could vote this feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19119145-powershell-script-support-in-activity

Comment: @SanjayJanardhan If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how introducing IR will help when the question is about running with an exe. "you need using the self-hosted integration to access the file in it:" this answer is misleading